# Which of these coding strategies is better in typescript and why?

Tags: typescript

```
class Abc{
 private arrayVariable1 = [];
 private arrayVariable2 = undefined;
 }
```

In case of arrayVariable1, it is by default initialised to empty array and later elements are pushed into it.
In case of arrrayVariable2, it is by default undefined and later changed to array and elements pushed to it.
Does arrayVariable1 takes memory even when it is empty as compared to arrayVariable2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None ! ;)

This optimization does not bring much and the priority should be set on showing intent and enforcing immutability as much as possible.

To do this, type the variable and make it readonly

```
class Abc{
   private readonly arrayVariable1: string[];

   constructor() {
      arrayVariable1 = []
   }
}
```

`readonly` is only really enforced at compile time but is a good protection against wrong assignment further down

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I worked on the Chakra JavaScript engine while at Microsoft)

> Does arrayVariable1 takes memory even when it is empty as compared to arrayVariable2?

Yes, an empty array uses more memory than an `undefined` or `null` value because of internal `Array` object state and initialization.

Given the performance impact of micro-optimizations such as late-initializing a property are negligible and necessarily add to code-complexity cost (as in your example you will need to check to see if `arrayVariable` is both not-`undefined` and not-`null` when your code might first add a value to the list. The code will be more readable and understandable to subsequent programmers if you eagerly-initialize the property to an empty array using `= []`.

Regarding your use of `private arrayVariable2 = undefined`: you should use `null` instead if you want to define an "unset" or empty initial property value. `undefined` has special rules and it's easy to shoot yourself in the foot with it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined - and using `undefined` in a `class` is counter-productive because you're undoing the performance benefits of classes as opposed to runtime-defined prototype objects.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issues with using `undefined` on an instance member causing deoptimizations?